# Expressing Logical Constness In Haskell

Tags: haskell, data-structures, constants

Data structures have mutating and non-mutating operations. For example, a dictionary insert can change the the state of its underlying data structure, but a lookup typically does not.

Some data structures mutate their internal structure - even on logically non-mutating operations - but in a manner which does not alter the observable state. E.g., a [splay tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) moves elements towards the root on lookup, and a [move-to-front list](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/JamesStewart/378notes/13mtf/) moves elements towards the head on lookup. Logically, the set of keys is unaltered by this.

In C++, this can be conveyed by defining a data structure that has `const` methods but [`mutable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) data members. Is there a way of doing this in Haskell? The only thing I can come up with is

```
setContains :: Set k -> k -> (Set k, Bool)
```

but this is ugly, as the underlying data structure changes the interface.

Comment: By definition everything is inmutable in haskell

Comment: maybe it's ugly - but it's honest too

Comment: @DanielSanchez Thanks, my question was if there's something I missed of getting around that.

Comment: @Carsten Not so sure about that. In C++, e.g., "overriding" a `const` method definition via `mutable` *isn't* considered dishonest as long as logical constness is preserved.

Comment: there are only **unsafe** things you could use to circumvent this (basically `unsafePerformIO`)

Comment: @Carsten Ah, thanks! I'll read up on that.

Comment: @AmiTavory it's dishonest form a Haskell perspective as you *do* mutate the structure - it's a philosophical thing - a MLer or F#er would agree with you - but you could argue that it's observable (you'll find the answer faster next time) ... please take care with this stuff - while I can see that it might be a good use case here it easily leads to all the problems we claim to have solved in Haskell ;)

Comment: @Carsten OK, many thanks!

Comment: @Carsten To point out something in favour of your view, in C++ there's a tremendous problem when accessing these types of containers via threads: the interface says it's `const`, but there are obviously data races when two threads do (even only) lookups.

Comment: The general Haskell idiom is, if a tool has some uses which violate some fundamental property of programs/data (e.g. immutability), then the tool is regarded as unsafe, and either not available or discouraged. C++ `mutable` falls in this bucket: abusing it, you could change visible state. C++ hands you dangerous tools and says "if you play dirty tricks with it, the guarantee is voided (UB, etc.)". This fits perfectly in the C++ (and C) philosophy. In Haskell, these things are hidden as much as possible, discouraged as much as possible: without those, there's no UB or "funny" semantics.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @chi - still trying to figure out Haskell.

Comment: If you want to implement a fundamentally mutable data structure in Haskell, you should give it a mutable interface. This way you do not worry about breaking the semantics of Haskell. This doesn't mean you must require your user to manually keep track of which set is which - you could write e.g `setContains :: Set k -> k -> IO Bool`.

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks for your comment; I will definitely look into what you suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This low-level optimization can not be achieved without using unsafe primitives, so to allow the mutation of data structures from pure code.

First of all, note that in the GHC runtime, pure code *does* modify data structures -- by evaluating them. E.g.

```
x = (3+2, 4+5)
main = print (fst x) >>> print (fst x)
```

In GHC, the first `print` call will actually *rewrite* `x` as `(5, 4+5)`, rewriting its first component with the result. In this way, the second `print` does not have to perform the addition a second time.
Of course, this rewriting will never change the semantics of `x`, so it is a special, "safe" kind of mutation.

Sometimes this is not enough to achieve some low-level optimizations, like the ones which are described in the question. Then, unsafe primitives are the only option.

I believe that the paragon example of this technique is [`Data.Array.Diff`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.2.0.0/docs/Data-Array-Diff.html). This is an *immutable* array data structure with a constant time access and update (!). Under the hood, there is a mutable array where updates are performed in place, imperatively. Since this would horribly break old references to the *immutable* array, such references are made to point also to a (mutable) "changelog" storing the old values before the updates. Hence, we get a kind of "revision control" system: the last version is fast, and old ones become slower and slower to access.
From the outside, only pure behaviour can be observed; inside, a lot of mutation happens.

The implementation uses `MVar`s to block concurrent accesses, to avoid the multithreading issues which the OP described in a comment above.

Let me stress again that this kind of tricks are definitely regarded as unidiomatic in Haskell. In everyday programming, this is *not* the way to write good, readable, solid Haskell code.

Comment: `DiffArray` has long been obsolete.. it isn't in any recent version of `array`. `array-0.2.0.0`, the last version containing it, is 8 years(!) old.

Comment: @user2407038 True, yet I can't find any better example. I am mentioning it more for the idea than the practice. If you know of modern "pure interface/mutability inside" examples, feel free to suggest one.

Comment: Ed Kmett's been working on some in the last year or so. Weird structures that can be switched cheaply between mutable and immutable forms.